# How to pass variable with `request` module

Tags: json, node.js, request

I'm using [request](https://www.npmjs.org/package/request) to get data from `json`. But, I don't know how to pass variable.

```
request.get('http://domain/to.json', function (error, response, body) {
    var json_body = JSON.parse(body);
});

console.log(json_body);
```

But, `json_body` is not defined.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Node.js function returns undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14895707/node-js-function-returns-undefined)

Answer (score 0):

Put your console.log() inside the request callback or create a separate function for your console.log() and call that from your request callback. There's lots of different ways to go about it (you might look into the `async` module if you're doing a lot of asynchronous function calls together).